# Diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

I've been dealing with this problem. Show that 
$$\varphi(x,y)=(x+f(y),y+f(x))$$
is a differmorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ onto itself when $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuously differentiable function with $|f'(t)|\leq k < 1$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ (consequently $f$ is a contraction). I have two questions:

1. I've already shown $\varphi$ is differentiable and bijective. Any idea for the differentiability of $\varphi^{-1}$?
2. Is there some way of proving $\varphi$ is surjective without using Bannach contraction fixed point theorem?

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Do you mean $|f'(t)|\le k<1$?

Comment: If you can show that the Jacobian of $\varphi$ is everywhere regular, then the differentiability of $\varphi^{-1}$ follows from the inverse function theorem (or a corollary thereof).

Comment: I've done the correcion, Adam. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that Jacobian of $\varphi$ is given by

$$
d\varphi_{(x,y)} \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & f'(y) \\
f'(x) & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

and this has determinant $1 - f'(x) f'(y)$.  Since $f'(t) <1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that the determinant is nonsingular at every point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ hence the inverse function theorem applies everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence $\varphi$ is locally diffeomorphic everywhere.  The fact that $\varphi$ is a map of constant rank and is bijective, it follows that $\varphi$ is a global diffeomorphism by the constant rank theorem for manifolds.

Comment: Probably "and therefore is a diffeomorphism" deserves some comment about partitions of unity (at least, I had to stop and think about this)

Comment: In general, local diffeomorphism everywhere doesn't imply global diffeomorphism. The global bijectivity condition can't be omitted. For a counterexample, consider $$z\mapsto z^2,\, z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}.$$ So I'd like to suggest a rewording of "therefore is a diffeomorphism" which can be misleading to those who don't know that the OP has already proved bijectivity.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Hopefully my argument now is a little clearer, especially since the OP has proven to themselves that $\varphi$ is bijective.