# If $\varphi(x,y)=(x+f(y),y+f(x))$ with $|f'(t)|\le k<1$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ function, such that $|f'(t)|\le k<1$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Define $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by, $\varphi(x,y)=(x+f(y),y+f(x))$. Show that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism.

First I showed that $\varphi$ is injective, then I showed that it is a local diffeomorphism by the inverse function theorem.

Now I have to show, that $\varphi$ is surjective, to conclude that it is a global diffeomorphism.

What I thought was to show that $\varphi(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is open and closed, so it would be $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To show that  $\varphi(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is open, I would use the conclusions of the inverse function theorem to conclude that $\varphi(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the union of open sets, to show that it is closed, it would suffice to show that Cauchy's sequences converge to the set.

In this last part, to show that $\varphi$ is surjective, I  think that what I thought is a little laborious, I wanted to know if there is a more direct way to conclude the surjective of $\varphi$.

I ended up encountering this question, but everyone use Cauchy's sequence.

Comment: It seems that this has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092908/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1407924/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1760464/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092566/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cvarphi(x%2Cy)%3D(x%2Bf(y)%2Cy%2Bf(x))%24&p=1)

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but as I said, they use Cauchy sequences, my question is whether there is another way to demonstrate without using Cauchy.

Comment: Write $Jacobian(\phi)(x,y)$  what do you get ? What about the proper caracter of $\phi$ ?

Comment: What about this one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2092977/42969?